x, y, z = values.split() what is the problem with this line? why wont it split with this string?
def calculation(values):
    x, y, z = values.split()

    x = float(x)
    z = float(z)

    if y == "+":
       return x+z
    elif y == "-":
       return x-z
    elif y == "*":
       return x*z
    elif y == '/':
       return x/z


values = input("Enter mathematical values: ")
print(calculation(values)) 

I tried to put split(""),split(   ),split("   ") also putting a space for each variable ,I had expected that the arithmatic values would be assigned to x,z and y will hold the operator.But it is contuniousing showing the same error shown in the image.screenshot of the error 

you need to separate the three tokens with a space, otherwise split will not work. Your input must contain spaces:  1 + 1 instead of 1+1. You should  also run some test cases on your function and catch the possible exceptions. Like what happens if z=0? Or if you don't have three tokens? Or if the first or last tokens are not numeric?

Please [edit] your question to place text as text directly in the question, not as a link to an image.

post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly .
Text allows for quick copy and pictures do not.
how to ask

Please show us what values looks like by adding a print(values) inside your function.

also, you can see how the split() method works here:  https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Did you mean: x, y, z = values?

Does this answer your question? Split() not working?

Your input needs to have spaces inbetween each character. So instead of 1+1, input 1 + 1.
Alternativley if you do not want to use spaces then split via the following method using Regex:
import re

# Define regular expression pattern to match operators
operator_pattern = r'[-+*/]'

# Split the expression using the operator pattern
operands = re.split(operator_pattern, values)

# Extract operands and operator
x = int(operands[0])
z = int(operands[1])
y = re.search(operator_pattern, values).group()


I am in the middle of trying to learn Python's regex engine; this is a nice sample to work on.

If you always enter two numbers separated by a mathematical operator, you could do something like:
for operator in '+-*/':
    numbers = strnum.split(operator)
    if len(numbers) == 2:
        numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers]
        match operator:
            case '+':
                return numbers[0] + numbers[1]
            case '-':
                return numbers[0] - numbers[1]
            case '*':
                return numbers[0] * numbers[1]
            case '/':
                return numbers[0] / numbers[1]
            case _:
                return None

